# Log to console In Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

When I run this command in robomongo, I get a output with different rows:

```
 db.getCollection('houses').find({})
```

Now I tried to run the same command in the mongo shell:

I wrote a script `mongo.js`:

```
  conn = new Mongo();
  db = conn.getDB("development");

  db.getCollection('houses').find({});
```

Opened the console with:

```
  mongo --shell
```

And tried to run the command:

```
  > load('mongo.js')
  true
```

**I do not understand** why I get only `true` as output. I want to see the query output! What do I wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the shell script, instead of `console.log` you can use

`print()` // for plain texts,

or `printjson()` // for json

usage :

`printjson(db.getCollection('houses').find({}));`

Answer (score 6):

When using

```
printjson(db.getCollection('houses').find({}));
```

I get the output from the find object.

```
{
"_mongo" : connection to ***.***.***.***,
"_db" : *****,
"_collection" : ***.houses,
"_ns" : "*****.houses",
"_query" : {

},
"_fields" : null,
"_limit" : 0,
"_skip" : 0,
"_batchSize" : 0,
"_options" : 4,
"_cursor" : null,
"_numReturned" : 0,
"_special" : false,
"help" : function () {
print("find(<predicate>, <projection>) modifiers")
print("\t.sort({...})")
 ...........
}
```

if you use

```
db.getCollection('houses').find({}).forEach(printjson)
```

I get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

An advancement for bigger scripts to keep the overview:

```
executeCommandAndLogResult(
    "Rename the collection",
    () =>
        db.getCollection('collection_a').renameCollection("collection_b")
);

function executeCommandAndLogResult(commandName, command) {
    printjson("--------------------------- Result of '" + commandName + "'-----------------------------")
    printjson(command());
    printjson("------------------------------ End of '" + commandName + "'-----------------------------")
}
```

The result will look like this if the renaming was successfull:

```sh
"--------------------------- Result of 'Rename the collection'-----------------------------"
{ "ok" : 1 }
"------------------------------ End of 'Rename the collection'-----------------------------"
```

Or like this if not:

```
"--------------------------- Result of 'Rename the collection'-----------------------------"
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "source namespace does not exist",
        "code" : 26,
        "codeName" : "NamespaceNotFound"
}
"------------------------------ End of 'Rename the collection'-----------------------------"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
printjson(db.getCollection('houses').find({}));
```

Use the findOne:

```
printjson(db.getCollection('houses').findOne({...}));
```

Or, if you want to print multiple results, make sure to convert them to the array first:

```
printjson(db.getCollection('houses').find({}).toArray());
```